# How to interpret this conditional statement with regard to std::errc

Tags: c++, if-statement

I was reading an example of how to use `std::from_chars` function [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars), when I came by the following if statment:

```
if(auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), result);
       ec == std::errc())
        std::cout << result << "\n" "p -> \"" << p << "\"\n";
```

Unfortunately I can not understand what `ec == std::errc()` means and how is it the condition. Does it mean that if `ec` (the possible error) is equal to default value of enum class `errc` the the following line should be executed? if so isn't that also an error?

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: `std::errc()` is an `errc` with a value of 0, which means success.

Comment: @interjay thank you very much. That was exactly what I wanted to know but from the definition of the enum class I could not find this default value.

Comment: It's 0 for any enum, and also for an integral, floating-point types, and for pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if(auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), result);
       ec == std::errc())
        std::cout << result << "\n" "p -> \"" << p << "\"\n";
```

is similar to

```
auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data()+str.size(), result);
if( ec == std::errc() )
    std::cout << result << "\n" "p -> \"" << p << "\"\n";
```

---

Long answer .. based on manual [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) the result for `std::from_chars` is  defined as

```
struct from_chars_result {
    const char* ptr;
    std::errc ec;
};
```

and based on errc [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errc) `std::errc()` is a condition for `success` OTOH the individual errors can be compared using `ec.code()`